# Cannot load google fonts in localhost (Visual Studio IIS Express)

Tags: visual-studio, google-maps-api-3, cors, google-font-api

In my `<head>` section of the page, I referenced some google fonts:

```
<link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,900,300,700" 
      rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" data-noprefix />
```

It loads well if I open the html page in the browser.

But when it is opened in Visual Studio IIS Express, which means the url is

```
http://localhost:1512/...
```

instead of

```
file:///C:/...
```

I got an error that looks like CORS issue:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,900,300,700.
>
> No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
>
> Origin `'http://localhost:1512'` is therefore not allowed access.

Anyone know what went wrong here?

Comment: I tried the same and it works for me, so I've got no idea what is wrong...

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem and I can resolve it adding in web.config debug="true" at line:

```
<compilation targetFramework="4.6" debug="true" />
```